# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (jar file already linked and placed in WEB-INF/lib)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

The solutions I found for this error were "add the jar file via build path" and "put the jar file containing the driver in WEB-INF/lib" (and similar formulations) but I already tried the two of them.

Back to my problem. Here is my Code:

jsp-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="db.DBAccess" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<jsp:useBean id="dba" class="db.DBAccess"></jsp:useBean>

<jsp:setProperty name="dba" property="selection" value="s" /> 

</body>
</html>
```

javabean

```
package db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBAccess {

    public DBAccess() {
    }

    private String selection = "";

    public void setSelection(String s) {

        final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String user = "user1";
        String pswd = "user1pswd";

        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            // initialize connection
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pswd);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            // execute select
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM t");
            results.next();
            selection =  results.getString(1);
            // close connection
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.out.println(cnfe.toString());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            }

    }
}
```

The content of t is one column with the label "string" and the content "hello world"

Why am I getting this exception even though I linked the jar file correctly?

Comment: Which jar did you add?

Comment: Try without `Class.forName`, just using `DriverManager` as documentation say here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager

Comment: I downloaded and installed "mysql java connector" from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=414247 Then I added the jar-file located in the installation folder of the mysql connector. I even tried to copy the jar-file into WEB-INF/lib and add this as external jar-file. It didn't work.

Comment: When removing the `Class.forName` line, I get the following error message: `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test`

Comment: Maybe I should also say that I tried the whole thing in a "normal" java class before and there it worked. Now I want to display my selection from the database on a website (through jsp) and I get this error message...

Answer (score 0):

Did you insert your jar file to lib folder of Webinf?

Comment: Are you using tomcat?